# How do I get Hagia Sophia to be revealed after collecting all 10 of the Memoir Pages?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In Assassin's Creed: Revelations, I have already collected all 10 of the Ishak Pasha Memoir pages, but the location of Hagia Sophia is not revealed.

I have found this location from guides online, but I do not seen an entrance for me to interact with.

Does anyone know what I could be missing?

Comment: Just wondering...is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Grr. I'm getting the same thing. I can't interact with the entrance despite having collected all 10 pages. Staring right at it, but it's not lit up. Did you ever find an answer for this one? I'm wondering if it's because I went back and collected them via the DNA menu after I'd moved into sequence 7 (capadoccia) in the main story...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when playing.

It turned out that there is a page or something else that is collectible right around the same marker location for the entrance, so unless you're really zoomed in on the map, you won't notice it.

I had to zoom in on my map a lot, and even then the markers were really close together.

If you're still having trouble, watch this video and it'll show you how to get in (as well as do the challenge).

Comment: thanks. But I couldn't find another page...how do I find it if there's no indicator?

Comment: Added a video that will hopefully make it easier for you

Comment: thanks a lot for the link Joseph. However, I already know where the entrance is, but I cannot interact with the entrance (ie. it doesn't shine). I'm still missing something that I cannot find.

Comment: ah that sucks! sounds like you may be bugged? or maybe you didn't find all the pages?

Comment: does your game say you have it unlocked?

Comment: it did say it was unlocked..and if I go to my inventory/Memoir Pages, it says it's "Completed"...oh dear...rage-quit-uninstall time? :(

Comment: @czchlong - That won't solve anything.  It sounds like your missing something.